# ERROR:[mapper_parsing_exception] Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: "Elasticserach"

Tags: api, elasticsearch, mapping

I'm trying to send SendGrid events to kibana, I am getting the following error

```
[root@elasticsearch-7 /]# sendgrid-event-logger

Installing template..
ERROR:[mapper_parsing_exception] Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [log : {dynamic_templates=[{string_fields={mapping={fielddata={format=disabled}, index=analyzed, omit_norms=true, type=string, fields={raw={index=not_analyzed, type=string}}}, match_mapping_type=string, match=*}}], properties={date={format=yyyy.MM.dd, type=date}, sg_message_id={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, ip={index=not_analyzed, type=ip}, sg_event_id={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, event={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, email={fielddata={format=disabled}, index=analyzed, omit_norms=true, type=string, fields={domain={analyzer=email_domain_analyzer, index=analyzed, type=string}, raw={index=not_analyzed, type=string}}}, timestamp={format=epoch_second, type=date}}}] :: {"path":"/_template/sendgrid_template","query":{},"body":"{\"template\":\"mail-*\",\"settings\":{\"number_of_shards\":1,\"index\":{\"analysis\":{\"tokenizer\":{\"email_domain_tokenizer\":{\"type\":\"pattern\",\"pattern\":\"^.+@\",\"group\":-1}},\"analyzer\":{\"email_domain_analyzer\":{\"type\":\"custom\",\"tokenizer\":\"email_domain_tokenizer\"}}}}},\"mappings\":{\"log\":{\"dynamic_templates\":[{\"string_fields\":{\"match\":\"*\",\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"analyzed\",\"omit_norms\":true,\"fielddata\":{\"format\":\"disabled\"},\"fields\":{\"raw\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"}}}}}],\"properties\":{\"email\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"analyzed\",\"omit_norms\":true,\"fielddata\":{\"format\":\"disabled\"},\"fields\":{\"raw\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"domain\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"analyzed\",\"analyzer\":\"email_domain_analyzer\"}}},\"timestamp\":{\"type\":\"date\",\"format\":\"epoch_second\"},\"date\":{\"type\":\"date\",\"format\":\"yyyy.MM.dd\"},\"event\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"ip\":{\"type\":\"ip\",\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"sg_event_id\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"sg_message_id\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"}}}},\"aliases\":{\"mail\":{}}}","statusCode":400,"response":"{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"mapper_parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [log : {dynamic_templates=[{string_fields={mapping={fielddata={format=disabled}, index=analyzed, omit_norms=true, type=string, fields={raw={index=not_analyzed, type=string}}}, match_mapping_type=string, match=*}}], properties={date={format=yyyy.MM.dd, type=date}, sg_message_id={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, ip={index=not_analyzed, type=ip}, sg_event_id={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, event={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, email={fielddata={format=disabled}, index=analyzed, omit_norms=true, type=string, fields={domain={analyzer=email_domain_analyzer, index=analyzed, type=string}, raw={index=not_analyzed, type=string}}}, timestamp={format=epoch_second, type=date}}}]\"}],\"type\":\"mapper_parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [log : {dynamic_templates=[{string_fields={mapping={fielddata={format=disabled}, index=analyzed, omit_norms=true, type=string, fields={raw={index=not_analyzed, type=string}}}, match_mapping_type=string, match=*}}], properties={date={format=yyyy.MM.dd, type=date}, sg_message_id={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, ip={index=not_analyzed, type=ip}, sg_event_id={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, event={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, email={fielddata={format=disabled}, index=analyzed, omit_norms=true, type=string, fields={domain={analyzer=email_domain_analyzer, index=analyzed, type=string}, raw={index=not_analyzed, type=string}}}, timestamp={format=epoch_second, type=date}}}]\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"mapper_parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [log : {dynamic_templates=[{string_fields={mapping={fielddata={format=disabled}, index=analyzed, omit_norms=true, type=string, fields={raw={index=not_analyzed, type=string}}}, match_mapping_type=string, match=*}}], properties={date={format=yyyy.MM.dd, type=date}, sg_message_id={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, ip={index=not_analyzed, type=ip}, sg_event_id={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, event={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, email={fielddata={format=disabled}, index=analyzed, omit_norms=true, type=string, fields={domain={analyzer=email_domain_analyzer, index=analyzed, type=string}, raw={index=not_analyzed, type=string}}}, timestamp={format=epoch_second, type=date}}}]\"}},\"status\":400}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running ES 7 and sendgrid-event-logger hasn't been updated for 4 years now. Multiple mapping types are not supported anymore and the default mapping type is now named `_doc`, while sendgrid-event-logger uses a custom one named `log`. So, you need to make the following three changes and it should work.

1. In [`lib/elasticsearch-template.json`](https://github.com/slebetman/sendgrid-event-logger/blob/02f7f667e8b00ee95e8c14a8259c3c115867923f/lib/elasticsearch-template.json), just change the following on line 24:

Replace

```
"log"
```

With

```
"_doc"
```

2. In [`lib/parser.js`](https://github.com/slebetman/sendgrid-event-logger/blob/02f7f667e8b00ee95e8c14a8259c3c115867923f/lib/parser.js#L43), make the following change on line 43:

Raplace

```
_type: 'log'
```

With

```
_type: '_doc'
```

3. In [`lib/server.js`](https://github.com/slebetman/sendgrid-event-logger/blob/02f7f667e8b00ee95e8c14a8259c3c115867923f/lib/server.js#L43), make the following change on line 43:

Raplace

```
type: 'log'
```

With

```
type: '_doc'
```

And it should work